# isov2 document class and definition list

Tags: formatting, lists

I am currently using the **isov2** document class.  I would like to create a list of definitions.  I currently have the following output (style)

[image: Current Definitions List Formatting]

using the code:

```
\begin{definitions}
\definition{agent}{Device that provides data in a manager-agent communicating system.}
\end{definitions}
```

However, I'd like instead for the term and definition to be on one line, separated by a colon, similar to the image below:

[image: Ideal Definitions List Formatting]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need a redefinition of the `definitions` environment to suppress some hard-coded line break commands and to add the colon:

```
\documentclass{isov2}

\makeatletter
\renewenvironment{definitions}{%
  \setcounter{cl@level}{6}
  \ifnum\value{sssssclause}=0 \setcounter{cl@level}{5} \fi
  \ifnum\value{ssssclause}=0 \setcounter{cl@level}{4} \fi
  \ifnum\value{sssclause}=0 \setcounter{cl@level}{3} \fi
  \ifnum\value{ssclause}=0 \setcounter{cl@level}{2} \fi
  \ifnum\value{sclause}=0 \setcounter{cl@level}{1} \fi
  \ifnum\value{clause}=0 \setcounter{cl@level}{0} \fi
  \ifcase\value{cl@level} % 0, NOT YET IN A CLAUSE
    \ClassWarning{iso}{Definitions started before the initial clause}
    \renewcommand{\@defcl}[1]{\setcounter{note}{0}\setcounter{example}{0}
      \par
      \addvspace{\beforecskip}
      \@afterindentfalse
      \refstepcounter{clause}
      {\raggedright\bfseries \theclause\ ##1:}}
  \or % 1, called in a clause
    \renewcommand{\@defcl}[1]{\setcounter{note}{0}\setcounter{example}{0}
      \par
      \addvspace{\beforescskip}
      \@afterindentfalse
      \refstepcounter{sclause}
      {\raggedright\bfseries \thesclause\ ##1:}}
  \or % 2, called in an sclause
    \renewcommand{\@defcl}[1]{\setcounter{note}{0}\setcounter{example}{0}
      \par
      \addvspace{\beforesscskip}
      \@afterindentfalse
      \refstepcounter{ssclause}
      {\raggedright\bfseries \thessclause\ ##1:}}
  \or % 3, called in an ssclause
    \renewcommand{\@defcl}[1]{\setcounter{note}{0}\setcounter{example}{0}
      \par
      \addvspace{\beforesscskip}
      \@afterindentfalse
      \refstepcounter{sssclause}
      {\raggedright\bfseries \thesssclause\ ##1:}}
  \or % 4, called in an sssclause
    \renewcommand{\@defcl}[1]{\setcounter{note}{0}\setcounter{example}{0}
      \par
      \addvspace{\beforesscskip}
      \@afterindentfalse
      \refstepcounter{ssssclause}
      {\raggedright\bfseries \thessssclause\ ##1:}}
  \or % 5, called in an ssssclause
    \renewcommand{\@defcl}[1]{\setcounter{note}{0}\setcounter{example}{0}
      \par
      \addvspace{\beforesscskip}
      \@afterindentfalse
      \refstepcounter{sssssclause}
      {\raggedright\bfseries \thesssssclause\ ##1:}}
  \else % 5+, called in an sssssclause or lower
    \ClassWarning{iso}{Definitions too deeply nested}
    \renewcommand{\@defcl}[1]{
      \par
      \addvspace{\beforesscskip}
      \@afterindentfalse
      \refstepcounter{sssssclause}
      {\raggedright\bfseries \thesssssclause\ ##1:}}
  \fi}%
  {}
\makeatother
\begin{document}

\clause{Test clause}
\sclause{Test sclause}
\begin{definitions}
\definition{agent}{Device that provides data in a manager-agent communicating system.}
\end{definitions}

\end{document}
```

The result:

[image]